# I want to generate a specific number of submatrices from a big one

Tags: matlab

I have A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15; 9 8 7; 8 7 6; 7 6 5]

How can I substract four matrices A1=[1 2 3; 4 5 6] A2=[7 8 9; 10 11 12] A3=[13 14 15; 9 8 7] A4 = [8 7 6; 7 6 5], whit a for loop, considering A1,A2,A3 and A4 names of submatrices. Thanks.

Comment: Why a for loop? `A1=A([1 2], :);` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you have a variable `num` to indicate number of output matrices you want (in this case, 4), try this:

```
B = cell(1, num);
B_size = size(A, 1) / num;

for i = 1:num
    B{i} = A((B_size * (i - 1) + 1):B_size * i, :);
end
```

`B` will be a cell array with four elements, equal to your idea of `A1` through `A4`. Obviously, values of `num` that don't evenly divide the total number of columns will not work well.

Comment: @user3365984, no problem. If my answer or another works, you should feel free to accept one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [ 1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9; 10 11 12; 13 14 15; 9 8 7; 8 7 6; 7 6 5];
for ii = 1:(length(A)/2)
    eval(['A' num2str(ii) '=A(' num2str(2*ii-1) ':' num2str(2*ii) ',:)'])    
end
```

The solution uses eval. 'A' num2str(ii) corresponds to A1, A2, A3 and A4. The for loop goes from 1 to 4 (length(A)/2 = 4)

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly. However, what can I change in the loop if I want only 3 matrices with 3 rows or 2 matrices with 4 rows?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining different variables `A1`,  `A2`, ..., it may be better to reshape the original matrix `A` like this

```
A = permute(reshape(A, [2 size(A,1)/2 size(A,2)]), [1 3 2]);
```

so that now `A(:,:,1)`, `A(:,:,2)`, ... correspond to your desired variables `A1`, `A2`, ...